# excel VBA return result of function

Tags: excel, vba

Simple Layup for anyone. I've written a function `isMac()` which looks at the current operating System, if the first 3 letters are Mac, it is supposed to return `True`. I then want to assign the return value of the function to a variable in another function. I'm currently running a Mac, so when I run the following code, the `MsgBox` says `True`, while the `Debug.Print` returns `False`

```
Function isMac() As Boolean
  If Left(Application.OperatingSystem, 3) = "Mac" Then
    result = True
  Else
    result = False
  End If
  MsgBox result
End Function

Sub test()
  Debug.Print isMac()
End Sub
```

How do I correctly return a Boolean from my IF statement so that I can utilize it in another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning the result to the function.

```
Function isMac() As Boolean
  isMac = CBool(LCase(Left(Application.OperatingSystem, 3)) = "mac")
End Function

Sub test()
  Debug.Print isMac()
End Sub
```

Another approach would be Compiler Directives and [Compiler Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264614.aspx). In a module code sheet's declarations area as,

```
#If Mac Then 
    Public Const bMAC as Boolean = True
#Else 
    Public Const bMAC as Boolean = False
#End If
```

Use `bMAC` anywhere in your code to determine whether the OS is a Mac or not.